# How did Jem's independent holograms project sound?

Tags: jem-and-the-holograms

In the 80s cartoon *Jem and the Holograms* the titular character could make realistic holographic projections... *within thin air*... via remote linkup with her sentient A.I. computer, Synergy. Synergy herself could tap into other computers and sound systems, and said she could manipulate the images via the "micro projectors", which were in Jem/Jerrica's earrings. This creates a problem, however: it would mean at least one earring would need to be within *some kind of range* to project the image.

Even if we take for granted that the earrings could create illusions with no sort of screen up to... let's say, 100 feet in every direction....

**How would these "images" produce the *sounds* that are meant to go with them?**

Logically, that would require the sound waves to travel from *some* type of source... which would, by most assumptions, be Jem's earrings. Yet, on multiple occasions, we see Jem project holograms that *also give off sound* which are *well* outside her immediate area, and often with a lot of ambient noise. Here, for instance, a small hologram is pestering the antagonist, Pizzazz, by being her "conscience"... but there should be **no way** the earrings Jem is wearing from 3 cars behind should be able to maintain a stable *image,* let alone project sound Pizzazz can hear...

[image: Hologram giving off sound]

Even if we take into account that Synergy used a radio in the car to carry the sound... which is *possible*, in that case... it doesn't account for the dozen or so *other* times Jem has projected a far away image, and it made sound **with *no* other technological source nearby to produce it.**

Was this ever explained, even as a handwave, in the show?